# Convex conjugate of a differentiable function

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex and differentiable everywhere. For $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define $$f^*(y) := \sup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \lbrace y\cdot x - f(x)\rbrace$$ Define $D = \lbrace\nabla f(x): x \in \mathbb{R}^n\rbrace$. Is it the case that if $y \not\in D$, then $f^*(y) = \infty$?

Comment: Ok, you are exactly asking whether a concave differentiable function $F$ such that $\nabla F$ never vanishes is unbounded above. (Indeed, just take $F(x)=y\cdot x -f(x)$). Do you think this is the case? (BTW I am not sure about pineapple coffee. :-D)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I see, thanks. It's false in general. In 1d, one can take $F(x) = -e^x$ as the counterexample. (You may like pineapple coffee if you don't take it seriously as a kind of coffee. It's nice as a kind of beverage.)

Comment: @Ilovepineapplecoffee it is true if you have $y\notin \overline{D}$, by the way.

Comment: @max_zorn This is indeed very useful to me. Could you point me to a reference for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is false. Set $n=1$ and take $f(x) = e^x$.
Then $0\not\in D$ but $f^*(0) = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\lbrace-e^x\rbrace=0$.

Comment: Right. To be fair, I thought that might be true for a minute, but this counterexample clearly shows I was wrong. (Also, you did not succeed in convincing me to put pineapple in my coffee :-D )