# Is convex conjugate infinite outside closed convex hull of gradients?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

<sub>This question is related to [Convex conjugate of a differentiable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4706978)</sub>

---

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex and differentiable everywhere. For $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define $$f^*(y) := \sup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \lbrace y\cdot x - f(x)\rbrace.$$ Set $D = \lbrace\nabla f(x): x \in \mathbb{R}^n\rbrace$. Let $\overline{\mathrm{conv}D}$ be the closed convex hull of $D$.
Is it the case that if $y \not\in \overline{\mathrm{conv}D}$, then $f^*(y) = \infty$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please provide your work thus-far in trying to arrive at a solution.

Comment: Since $y\not\in \overline{\mathrm{conv}D}$ implies $y\not\in D$ I am now really confused why you don't just apply your own counter example in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: @KurtG. That counterexample showed that there exists $y\not\in D$ such that $f^*(y)$ is finite. It does not work here because $y=0$ lives in $\overline{\mathrm{conv}D} = [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Relevant, albeit doesn't solve the problem immediately: It follows from the Fenchel-Young equality that $D\subset \textrm{dom} f^*$ [Corollary 16.11, Bauschke/Combettes, vol. 2], so you are asking about whether or not the reverse inclusion holds after closure. If you like Fitzpatrick functions, exercise 20.14-20.15 in the same book might be helpful.

Comment: (also, for a convex function $f$, $D$ should be convex, so we don't have to worry about the $\textrm{conv}$ part of the problem.)